# detached thread, free arg pointer

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers

I use a pthread_create which calls a function with its arguments in a struct pointer.

I have to detach the thread because I don't want the main program to wait for the thread to finish.

How can I free the struct pointer after detaching the thread?

```
int s;
struct thread_args *t_args = malloc(sizeof(struct thread_args));
t_args->bn = basename;
t_args->mf = max_files;
t_args->mfs= max_file_size;


s = pthread_create(&t_id, NULL, archiver, t_args);
if(s != 0)
  {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
  return 1;
  }
  else {
       free(t_args);
       }

                if (days > 0)
                {
                    delete(basename,days);
                }
                s = pthread_detach(t_id);
```

Above only the snippet that won't work.

Comment: define "won't work"; errors? segfaults? stuff not being freed (if that's the case, how do you notice)?

Comment: I do a valgrind leak check, and it tells me that there are definitely lost blocks at : 

    struct thread_args *t_args = malloc(sizeof(struct thread_args));

Comment: @Merl What happens if you just `free(t_args);` in the thread function?

Comment: If you don't know what the thread does with the args, you **don't** free it.  And you definitely don't free it until you know for sure the thread is done with it - either in the thread itself, or in the creating thread **after** the child thread signals in some way (semaphore, perhaps) that it's OK to free the memory.  You certainly **can't** free it as you are doing - immediately after calling `pthread_create()`.  The new thread likely hasn't even started yet.